# Enumerate array of hash with Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I've already spent 2h trying different solution involving hash and array but I didn't find how to iterate through my array of hash:

I created an array like this:

```
my @matches;
push @matches, {file => $1, function => $2} while m/KEY_FILE \s* \{ [^\}]+ KEY_SECTION \s* \( \s* ([^()]+) \( ([^()]+) \) \s* \)/ixg;
my $count = @matches;
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
while (($file, $function) = shift(@matches)) {
    print "// File:     $file\n";
    print "// Function: $function\n";
}
```

But obviously this is not a solution :(

Any help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that it isn't appropriate to use a postfixed `while` (a *statement modifier*) when it makes the statement so long. This is far from being clear at a glance:

```
push @matches, {file => $1, function => $2} while m/KEY_FILE \s* \{ [^\}]+ KEY_SECTION \s* \( \s* ([^()]+) \( ([^()]+) \) \s* \)/ixg;
```

Even the standard `while` is clumsy because of the length of the regex.

```
while (/KEY_FILE \s* \{ [^\}]+ KEY_SECTION \s* \( \s* ([^()]+) \( ([^()]+) \) \s* \)/ixg ) {
  push @matches, { file => $1, function => $2 };
}
```

It is much better to separate the functionality of the regex and put it into its own variable:

```
my $re = qr{
    KEY_FILE \s*
    \{ [^\}]+ KEY_SECTION \s*
    \( \s*
      ( [^()]+ )
      \( ( [^()]+ ) \) \s*
    \)
}xi;

while ( /$re/g ) {
  push @matches, { file => $1, function => $2 };
}
```

That aside, once the `@matches` array has been built it is simplest to iterate over its values, which are hash references. Then you can extract each value pair using a *hash slice*. Like this

```
for my $href (@matches) {
   my ($file, $function) = @{$href}{qw/ file function /};
   print "// File:     $file\n";
   print "// Function: $function\n";
}
```

Or you could just continue to use the hash reference if the two values are accessed only a few times

```
for my $href (@matches) {
   print "// File:     $href->{file}\n";
   print "// Function: $href->{function}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would rather go with plain foreach,

```
for my $href (@matches) {
  my ($file, $function) = @$href{qw(file function)};
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    foreach my $match ( @matches ) {
         print "// File: $match->{file}\n";
         print "// Function: $match->{function}\n";
    }
```